# Rewrite block declaration explantation

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, configuration, xml

I want to know some detail in `config.xml` about rewriting block for exemple, usually when we create a block we need to declare it in a xml like this:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <moduleName> 
            <class>moduleNameSpace_moduleName_Block</class>
        </moduleName>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

But when we rewrite some module we dont declare it :

> We take product_view block rewrite for exemple

```
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <!--we haven't this-->
        <!--<moduleName>
                <class>moduleNameSpace_moduleName_Block</class>
            </moduleName>-->
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view>moduleNameSpace_moduleName_Block_Product_View</product_view>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
```

I know that it works but i want to know the explanation.

Comment: For your "we havent this" comment ... of course we have, its used for every custom block type?!? Or did i got it wrong?

Comment: Look sv3n, For now I have just rewrite `product_view` block of catalog module by `product_view` block of my custom module `catalog`, So in my module I have well created my block like this:  `Block/Product/View.php` But what I want to know is that since I have created my block In my custom module, logically I have to declare it in `config.xml` to tell to Magento: i have a block and then I tell him that this block `Product/View.php` it will rewrites the natif block of catalog module like my exemple.
for information my rewrites works fine, i have just to know this detail :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first declaration

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <moduleName> 
            <class>moduleNameSpace_moduleName_Block</class>
        </moduleName>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

You define this for your main module where blocks of your module are defined.

Now if you want to override/rewrite a block or model or helper to notify magento you need to use `<rewrite>` tag.

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_view>moduleNameSpace_moduleName_Block_Product_View</product_view>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Breaking this up is easy. In the string, `catalog`, tag you have defined is the module name magento looks for which in this case is Catalog. The  node goes inside of this. Then, inside `<rewrite/>` you define the block you need to override which is `product_view` so Magento looks for `Catalog/Block/Product/View.php` file.

And, `moduleNameSpace_moduleName_Block_Product_View` is the name of the class that is being loaded instead of `catalog/product_view`.

Comment: Thank you for your time but i know all this, i know how the rewrite works. My question is just why we dont declare our exsisting block. Logically we tel to magento : i have  block then i want to rewrite some block of some module like my exemple

Answer (score 2):

Still not sure if i got it right ... but let's try :)

For example look at your code and `catalog.xml` where you can find

```
<block type="catalog/product_view"
```

**Rewrite**:

```
<blocks>
    <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <product_view>Namespace_Name_Block_Product_View</product_view>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>
</blocks>
```

In this case all blocks of tpye `catalog/product_view` would use your logic from your block class.

**Own class:**

```
<blocks>
    <!--We have this -->
    <moduleName>
        <class>Namespace_Name_Block</class>
    </moduleName>
</blocks>
```

This had no effect to `catalog.xml` `<block type="catalog/product_view"`, but you can use tthis for your own (rewritten) blocks:

```
<block type="moduleName/product_view"
```

Comment: So if I understood correctly Magento could detect in the rewrite   `<product_view>Namespace_Name_Block_Product_View</product_view>`  my block without having to declare it before, the `<!--We have this -->` block ! the explanation is (we have entred the full class block `Namespace_Name_Block_Product_View`) so he dont need to check it in the xml declaration block. And if I ever have to use another simple block (not rewrite), at this moment I have to declare it as in my example `<!--We have this -->` block. right ?

Comment: Right. Hope this answered yor question. :)

Comment: Thank you for your time, the first answer is correct so I accept it but +1